# Mocha fails with variable not defined

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I use mocha to test a function in a file. The testable function is implemented like this:

**math.js**

```
(function (exports) {
    var MY_APP_ = MY_APP || {};
    MY_APP_.utils = MY_APP_.utils || {};
    MY_APP_.utils.math = MY_APP_.utils.math || {};

    MY_APP_.utils.math.randomValue = function (min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max + 1 - min) + min);
    };

    exports.math = MY_APP_.utils.math;

})(this);
```

And here is the test:
**math_test.js**

```
var assert = require("assert");
var math = require("../../js/utils/math.js");

describe('Math', function() {
    describe('randomValue', function () {
        it('should return random values', function () {
            // Fill array with random values between 0 and 10
            var values = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                values.push(math.math.randomValue(0, 10));
            }

            // Count numbers
            var result = {};
            values.forEach(function(number) {
                var numberAsString = number.toString();
                result[numberAsString] = result[numberAsString] + 1 || 1;
            });

            // There must be at least two of each number
            assert.equal(Object.keys(result).length, 11);
            Object.keys(result).forEach(function(key) {
                assert.equal(true, result[key] > 1);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

**The problem is that `var MY_APP_ = MY_APP || {};` fails with an error message: MY_APP is not defined.**

Sure, MY_APP is not defined in the scope of this test because it is defined in an another file called app.js. When I build the app, this app.js file is included before math.js and both of them are concatenated into a single production.js file. This works without problem.

The test works, however, if I replace the failing line with the following:

```
var MY_APP = {};
if (typeof(MY_APP) !== 'undefined') {
        MY_APP_ = MY_APP;
    } else {
        MY_APP_ = {};
    }
```

This looks stupid in my opinion. I would like to know the reason why mocha is failing since the code works perfectly well when I run it in a browser.

EDIT:
I think I have made a mistake. `var MY_APP_ = MY_APP || {};` seems to never work if MY_APP is not defined so the only option is to declare MY_APP before using math.js

Comment: It seems you're providing your own answer: _"When I build the app, this app.js is included before math.js"_. In other words, `math.js` depends on `app.js`.

Comment: Yes, but requiring app.js in the test does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From what you showed I would think that you would receive an error, and that your direct test works.

In your test you initialize `MY_APP` to an empty object which allows it to run. But in your `math.js` file `MY_APP` is never initialized, so when you set `var MY_APP = MY_APP` it would never be able to set it to anything.

I would suggest trying to initialize `MY_APP` before assigning it as a value for a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Since the only purpose of app.js to just initialize `var MY_APP = {};` to global scope I decided to do the same in the test file, so:

```
var assert = require("assert");
global.MY_APP = {};
var math = require("../../js/utils/math.js");
```

solves the problem